# Channels for applying for faculty positions

Tags: job-search, faculty-application, engineering, business-school

I am a postdoc in engineering at a large US university and am planning on applying for tenure-track faculty positions this fall.

I understand that the nature of applying for TT faculty positions varies greatly depending on the field. I am inquiring mainly about engineering schools and business schools (specifically operations research departments).

**My general question is**: *is there an organized procedure for how TT faculty openings are disseminated through the community?*

In my limited search so far, I have not seen much online in terms of job postings. The postings are either outdated or very sparse. Furthermore, there is no indication on university websites if the department is hiring or not.

**Related thoughts/concerns**: Is it acceptable to send an application to a department when there is no job posting? Are there more effective channels for applying: i.e., give a talk in the department and inform the head that I am interested in applying? Leverage connections to contact someone high up in the department?

Perhaps the lack of structure in the job hiring process is inherent or by design. Any guidance on the procedure (for engineering and/or operations research departments) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Some fields have one or two dominant professional organizations with a publication in which most jobs are posted. In computing we have ACM and IEEE. Perhaps your field has something similar.

Comment: You should talk to your advisors about this question and job search in general. This includes both your doctoral advisor, and your postdoc mentor if you have one.

Comment: Another aspect to keep in mind is *timing*.  It is now July 2019, and most US universities have probably not yet posted job openings for Fall 2020 (though again this can vary by field).  They may not even be certain yet whether they have an opening - there are many levels of approval needed to start a tenure-track search, even to fill an existing line.  So it's also possible you are looking in the right places but it's just too early.  In my field (math), jobs are usually posted in August or September, with an application deadline of November or December.

Comment: I don't think you'll find one web site or publication which is dominant in the broad area of OR (which lives variously in business schools, math departments, and industrial engineering departments.)  One useful site is the INFORMS careers web site at: https://connect.informs.org/careercenter/home

Comment: Although it's possible that you might be able to find a short term visiting position through word of mouth or having sent an unsolicited email, you can expect that any permanent tenure track position will be nationally advertised.

Comment: @Buffy For computer science, I would suggest CRA long before either ACM or IEEE.

Comment: Ah, yes, @JeffE, of course.